# How to install firmware from the Arch wiki

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, arch-linux, wiki

I have Debian on my Acer Laptop with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wifi card and wifi does not work.
Command System tray -> Wifi -> Wifi Technologies 1 Found, 0 Powered
I think I have to install extra firmware for this card.
After a bit of googeling I found this post https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=266280 .
It's exactly my problem, but I don't know what to do next.
It seams like you can download something by clicking "download from mirror", but what ever I downloaded by doing this, it looks like I have to build it and I don't know how.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci`, per https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=266280 ? See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678502/how-to-setup-qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-802-11ac-wireless-network-adapter-rev-31

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use them before, because modprobe was not installed and sudo apt modprobe didn't work. sudo apt kmod worked and I could use this command.

Comment: If the modem now works, why not answer your own question, and get credit, as well as helping other Arch Linux users? Thanks.

Comment: Because I made it work on my system with the command, but my question, which could help arch user wasn't answered yet.